# How do you configure windows to store the bitcoin blockchain data into another directory?

Tags: windows, datadir

I'm currently on windows and was wondering how do you make the qt client download the blockchain data to another directory? Since my main drive is a SSD hard drive, I don't have much space to spare. How would I configure this to make it download elsewhere?

Also would this apply to other qt clients like litecoin, ppcoin, etc?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add '-datadir=path-to-directory' to the command used to start the client.  For example,

```
bitcoin-qt -datadir=D:\Bitcoin
```

to store the bitcoin files in the D:\Bitcoin directory.  Remember to enclose the directory path in double quotes if it contains spaces.  Also move the subdirectories as well as the main application directory to the new location.

Comment: but what if im running a gui client? is there a setting somewhere? also does this also work for the other altcoins?

Comment: This works for bitcoind (the daemon) and bitcoin-qt (the GUI).  You must set it before starting the program since the program needs to know where to find its files.  By the time the GUI is displayed, the client has already verified its files and connected to the network.  This should work for other altcoins as long as they are built based on the bitcoin reference client.

Comment: Verified working on philosopher stones and datacoin-qt for windows. My suggestion is to create a .bat file and start it by running the bat file instead of the .exe file where it points to the other directory.