# Bitcoin Core for Mac not syncing, can't access private key

Tags: private-key, bech32-address, private-key-export

Wondering if you can help me guys, I'm new to using bitcoins and recently downloaded Bitcoin Core to my MacBook. I stupidly sent bitcoins to my wallet without realising i had to sync first, but it's been syncing for a week now and still has 1 year 46 weeks to go.

I have the phassprase but the bech 32 adress I cannot see the private key

Please help

Comment: What is your question? What do you need help with? Anything that wouldn't be solved by waiting a day or two for sync to complete?

Comment: Hey, first of all thanks a lot for your response. The problem is that I started de sync on my mac disk (245GB) so it's imposible to finish. I'm trying to save my public and private keys of my bech 32 segwit adresses to close bitcoin core and install then on a external disk. I dont want to lose the bech 32 adresses because I already sent funds. Im worried

Comment: But I dont find the way to export or see the private key. Dumpprivatekey dont work with bench 23. And im a noob programming so it's a little bit dificult for me to use de debug terminal.

Comment: The Problem is the lack of disk space to complete the sync? In this case I would suggest configuring pruning in Bitcoin Core so that it only keeps the last `x` blocks, along with the info relevant to your wallet. This will allow you to finish the sync. And verify that the funds are there.

Answer (score 1):

I can think of multiple possible avenues to resolve your issue:

1. FWIU, your computer has insufficient disk space to store the entire blockchain. You can configure your node to use [*pruning* mode](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/37496/5406), so that it does not keep the entire blockchain. This way, you can just let your computer finish synchronize.
2. Stop Bitcoin Core. Back up the wallet in at least one additional place. Move the Bitcoin directory to your external disk. [Configure your node](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/a/19912/5406) to use the directory on your external disk as its data directory. Continue synchronizing from there.
3. Stop Bitcoin Core. Back up your wallet file in at least two other places. (Test the backup!) Uninstall Bitcoin Core. Install Bitcoin Core on your external disk. Import your wallet.

I would generally not recommend exporting keys, as you may end up just exporting the master key, but not the derivation path or something similar. If you are using the GUI, use the wallet export function from the GUI to create a backup. Preferably, first test your backup by means of starting another installation on the external disk or a second device before you delete anything.

Comment: I can use pruning mode during sync or I need to do before start? I tried to back up but I don't know if the file that creates is correct. Generates a .dat file, It's Ok? And finaly where can I find Bitcoin directory on mac finder? (srry for the dumb question and thanks for your time!)

Comment: It should create a `wallet.dat`. Regarding directory, check out: https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/a/4007/5406. You can change it to pruning mode after it started synchronizing, but it’ll require restarting Bitcoin Core. I believe there should be a GUI option to set that.

Comment: Okay I find the directory but when I press back up wallet It opens to put a name, tag an specify where it goes, so It don't create a wallet.dat on bitcoin directory. And when I back up It saves all the receiptor adresses (3) to reopen again the 3 right? And with the backup file I also need the private key to import later? Or maybe ask me the phassprase?

Comment: The bitcoin directory already contains your original `wallet.dat`, so it does make sense for the backup to be stored in another directory. The `wallet.dat` and a backup contains the data to regenerate all private keys the wallet has ever derived and will ever derive and I would assume also any manually imported keys. If your wallet has a passphrase, you will need that later to import the backup

Comment: I have the wallet.dat file, now i'm trying to install Bitcoin core correctly on My external disk, how I have to do it properly to use my wallet.dat backup? Thanks

Comment: It should suffice to put it into the bitcoin directory of your new installation for it to load the wallet

Comment: Hi, thanks a lot for your help. I do what you say and a datadir to redirect correctly the blocks download and it works perfect. Thanks again